# convert objectId to hex value pymongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I obtained the objectId from the database as follows:

```
    for mem in each.member_of:
        member_ty.append(mem)
```

where 'mem' has the objectId.

each.member_of -- o/p --> [ObjectId('570e4c5da78dd04322f7a2a8')]

Now in order to convert to string , I did following steps:

```
    for mem in each.member_of:
        member_ty.append(str(mem))
```

the o/p would be 
['570e4c5da78dd04322f7a2a8']

The o/p required is : 570e4c5da78dd04322f7a2a8

How can I do it ?
I have tried toString(), valueOf() , tohexString(), but they dont work.

Comment: This is very unclear. `member_ty` is a list, and you append each value to it. Where exactly are you producing that output?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is passed to the template file. And I'm printing it there to check too.

Comment: And it's still a list there too. Maybe you should show what you're doing in the template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman the issue was that it was put in a list. On the template file if the list is looped and valueOf is applied while keeping the variable as ObjectId the desired o/p is obtained. And it successfully passed to other template. Thank you for your help.